# Border outline cannot be removed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap navbar and trying to get rid of border but it doesn't go!

```css
.navbar
{
 height: 100px;
}

.navbar-default
{
 /*background-color: #0050A0;*/
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0;
 border-color: none;
 border: 0 !important
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, white 45%, #12A8E0 85%, #0050A0 100%);

}

.flash_navbar a
{
 color: black !important;
}

.search_form
{
 width: 70%;
}

.nav_form
{
 border-radius: 0;
 margin-top: 27px;
}

#searchBar
{
 border-color: #0050A0;

}

#searchButton
{
 background-color: #0050A0;
 color: white;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="flash_navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" id="collapse_button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>
    </div>

     <form class="search_form" action="/product/search" method="POST">
      <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control nav_form" placeholder="Search" id="searchBar" />
       <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default nav_form" type="submit" id="searchButton">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </form>
    
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
```

This is the actual result in my browser. Snipplet doesnt seem to give correct result.

[image: Actual navbar]

I want to remove it's outline or border

Comment: Try `#searchBar { border: none; }`

Comment: `.navbar {border: none}`

Comment: Maybe because you are missing semicolon on the line `border: 0 !important`. If you want to remove outline from input, set `.form-control:focus { box-shadow: none; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap class is overriding yours. Try this.

```
.flash_navbar .navbar {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

By doing this you are targeting the class through your container which makes your new code render.

Answer (score 1):

Simple `#searchBar{ border: 0 }` should work

Using "Inspect element" in Chrome or it's alternative should help you find the right CSS selector to achieve required changes

Answer (score 1):

Check this block of css:

```
.navbar-default
{
/*background-color: #0050A0;*/
background-color: white;
border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-color: none;
border: 0 !important
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, white 45%, #12A8E0 85%, #0050A0 100%);

}
```

Notice the missing semi-colon after `!important`? That messes up your css from there on. Fix that to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Navbar border width and style is defined in the navbar class, not navbar-default. On your browser, you can check this by inspecting the element (on chrome, you can click on computed styles to verify). All you need to override is the class that defined it in the first place. This way, you don't even need to use `!important`

```
.navbar
{
    height: 100px;
    border: none;
}

.navbar-default {
    ...
}
```

[image: Navbar border defined on .navbar class]